# How to set boto3 connect timeout and read timeout using environment variables?

Tags: python, boto3

I'm dealing with a large existing python application and trying to set global defaults for all the boto3 resources and clients that don't have any specified. Since there are many of them, I don't want to update every place the resources are created to create a botocore Config object; so it seems to make sense to use the environment variable approach to configuration. I want to set 4 configurations related to timeout and retry, but of the 4, the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) only indicates that 2 of them can be set via environment variables. Same for configuring using a config file.

botocore.Config supports connect_timeout, read_timeout, retry mode, and retry max_attempts.

But the environment variables only support AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS and AWS_RETRY_MODE (at least according to the documentation). How to set the connect_timeout and read_timeout by environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at the moment.

It seems that [the environment variable names are all explicitly defined in botocore's config provider](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/master/botocore/configprovider.py).